# Uninitialized constant Admin::Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

Using Ruby: `2.3.1p112` and Rails: `3.2.12`

I'm trying call a demo method in my controller. So, in my `_form.html.erb` I have:

```
<%= link_to 'Demo', "/admin/clinics/"+@clinic.id.to_s+"/demo" %>
```

In my `routes.rb`:

```
match "/admin" => "admin#index", :as => :admin

namespace :admin do
    resources :admin_users
    resources :health_plan_tables
    resources :health_aid_tables
    resources :clients
    resources :clinics
    resources :specialties
    resources :qualifications
    resources :profissionals
    resources :addresses
    resources :documents
    resources :banners
    root :to => 'banners#index'
    get 'logout' => 'devise/sessions#destroy'

    get 'clinics/:id/demo', to: 'admin/clinics#demo', as: 'demo'
end
```

My `clinics_controller.rb` is inside the folder `controllers/admin`, and I just have:

```
def demo
    print "hello"
end
```

So, when I click on link, error message appears `Uninitialized constant Admin::Admin`.
Any ideia how to fix it?

Comment: Can you post the full error stacktrace?

Comment: Here man: [link](https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/image-png--479)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are already defining your `demo` route inside a namespace there is no need to specify `admin/clinics#demo`, just `clinics#demo` will be necessary:

```
namespace :admin do
    resources :admin_users
    resources :health_plan_tables
    resources :health_aid_tables
    resources :clients
    resources :clinics
    resources :specialties
    resources :qualifications
    resources :profissionals
    resources :addresses
    resources :documents
    resources :banners
    root :to => 'banners#index'
    get 'logout' => 'devise/sessions#destroy'

    get 'clinics/:id/demo', to: 'clinics#demo', as: 'demo'
end
```

Comment: I get `Missing template admin` error. [Check out](https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/image2-png--14).

Comment: @ThiagoAnderson That is because you don't have a view called `demo.html.erb` in `app/views/admin/clinics`; you must add that template. Or, if you just want to print `hello` in your browser, then change `print "hello"` to `render inline: "hello"`.

Comment: Nice @Gerry! Thats it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

According to the error log you're looking for a controller namespaced under admin/admin/clinics (it says that in the controller part of the params).

Change the bottom route to not include admin (it's already namespaced and you're effectively namespacing it twice):

```
get 'clinics/:id/demo', to: 'clinics#demo', as: 'demo'
```

This will route to the correct controller, admin/clinics, instead of admin/admin/clinics

Comment: I get `Missing template admin` error. [Check out](https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/image2-png--14).

Comment: I'll leave this one to Gerry.

Comment: Ohh :/ just noticed we answered at the same time (actually i did 1 min later).

Comment: You beat me to answering the second question so fair is fair :D